# Why does the display size not match the font size in homepage?

Tags: html

[look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXbr7.png)

the font size is set to 12px, why does it display 14px?

Comment: the 14px is not the font size, but the actual height of the rendered em tag

Answer (score 1):

The font size may be set to 12px, but the total height of the container of the words is not definitely 12px. When you highlight and select it this way, your browser will get the height of the container. A difference of 1px or 2px is not visible most of the time, this difference can be caused by the `padding` of the container.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but I can not find out the reason why it is 14px

Comment: 虽然十二是字体的宽大，不代表格式宽大是十二。当你鼠标选择哪几个字，整个包着字体的格式也被选择了。

Comment: 如果字体在屏幕上的确是十四大，很有可能有别的选择器覆盖了它原本设下的宽大

Comment: sorry i'm assuming you're chinese